# Removing multiple lines in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

So I've got a list of dns-name and i'd like to filter out all the ones that are generic using preferrably Notepad++.

So for example

```
Name: test-14.45.name.other.com  
Address: 192.168.14.45

Name: cottoncandy.fun.com  
Address: 192.168.14.46
```

Obviously the easiest part is to bookmark the generic names (`test-14.45`) and remove them since they all have some parts on the name in common.

So what I'm wondering is, how do I bookmark the address field below every non-generic dns-name?

Comment: What is your expected output? And, please give more examples and criteria.

Comment: My expected output is for the generic dns-names to be removed, as for their IP-addresses too. So that I can get a list of the non-generic dns-names and their IPs.

Comment: What character do you have after p-208? Are thay only digits, letter, any kind of character?

Comment: What lines do you want to delete? Only those that have `p208-` at the begionning of the name? Or other criteria?

Comment: 2 random digits.

Comment: I want to delete only the lines that starts with p208 and the address field below those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- <strike>Find what: `^Name:\h+test-\d+\.\d+.+\R.+(?:\R\R?|$)`</strike>
- Find what: `^Name:\h+p208-\d{1,2}.+\R.+(?:\R\R?|$)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
Name:       : literally
\h+         : 1 or more horizontal spaces
p208-       : literally
\d{1,2}     : 1 or 2 digits
.+          : 1 or more any character but newline
\R          : any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r or \n or \r\n)
.+          : 1 or more any character but newline
(?:         : start non capture group
    \R\R?   : 1 or 2 linebreak
  |         : OR
    $       : end of line
)           : end group
```

**Given:**

```
Name: p208-14.45.name.other.com  
Address: 192.168.14.45

Name: cottoncandy.fun.com  
Address: 192.168.14.46

Name: p208-14.44.name.other.com  
Address: 192.168.14.45
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Name: cottoncandy.fun.com  
Address: 192.168.14.46
```

Comment: I added a picture in my post, check it out. Can't get it to work. I feel pretty silly.

Comment: @Oscar: Have you got any message? What version of Notepad++? (Here, I have 7.5.8)

Comment: I'm running 7.5.7, no message.

Comment: @Oscar: See my edit. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Oscar: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can `Find` and remove them, use below regular expression to find entries to delete, than delete them.

`.*test-14\.45.*\r\nAddress.*`

make sure "regular expression" is selected and ". matches newline" is blank.

[image]

Comment: so if i wanted to mark every name that starts with "d142", and the address line below, how would i do that?

Comment: .*d142.*\r\nAddress.*